# change the color of placeholder when you select any value

Tags: html, css

i am also using pseudo class "option:checked" its not working ,when we select any value its color changes gray to black its ok but when you defocus the select field this color should black and initially placeholder should be gray.

```
<select>
    <option value="" hidden selected>Choose any...</option>
    <option>developer</option>
    <option>tester</option>
</select>
```

css also attached

```
 select {
  color: gray;
 }
 option{
  color:black;
 }
 select:focus{
  color: black;
 }
```

[image]
this developer color should be black color after selection of option

Comment: could you share the image of the outcome you are getting currently and what you want?

Comment: after selecting the option if you click any where the color of the selection should be black but its seems gray